# How to render validation errors on the page that submitted the form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, forms

I've got a comments form in the article/show page. In this page, it displays the article and has a comments form.

When I submit a comment that has validation errors, I need it to go back to the article/show page, and display the errors there.

Should I change `render :action => 'new'` to something else?

In the Comment controller, I tried:

```
  def create
    ...

    if @comment.save?
      redirect_to article_path(@comment.article), :notice => "Posted comment!"
    else
      # render :action => 'new'
      render 'articles/show"
    end
  end
```

But this will complain, since the app won't know which article to show based on the ID.

**EDIT:** I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512875/how-can-i-pass-validation-error-messages-to-a-method-in-a-different-controller) solution. The approach would be to use a session to pass the errors instead. Is this the right way to go with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
def create
    ...

    if @comment.save?
      redirect_to article_path(@comment.article), :notice => "Posted comment!"
    else
      # render :action => 'new'
      @article = @comment.article
      render 'articles/show"
    end
  end`
```

Comment: Thanks Pravin for the much more descriptive response. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175385/where-to-render-comments-controller-in-rails-on-model-validations-failure also seems to provde a similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

So fix your routing so the app *does* know what article to show based on the ID.